# FirebaseListObservable<any[]> as list for material 2 autocomplete not filtering

Tags: angularfire2, angular-material2, angular2-observables

I am trying to use angularfire2 and I want to use the angular material2 autocomplete component.  with my current setup, the autocomplete list is properly populated from firebase.  However the filter function does not seem to be working and I can't figure out why.  Is it because I am using switchmap instead of map like the material example is using(if I use map then the list is not populated and it throws errors)?  does the filter function work differently for a FirebaseListObservable vs a normal Observable?

The component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'budget-new-transaction',
  templateUrl: './new-transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-transaction.component.css']
})
export class NewTransactionComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  categoryCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredCategories: any;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<NewTransactionComponent>, public af: AngularFire, ) {
    this.categories = af.database.list('/items');
    this.categoryCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredCategories = this.categoryCtrl.valueChanges
      .startWith(null)
      .switchMap(name => this.filterCategories(name));
  }
  filterCategories(val: string) {
    return val ? this.categories.filter(s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s))
      : this.categories;
  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The html file

```
<h3>Add User Dialog</h3>
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="dialogRef.close(form.value)" ngNativeValidate>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="8px">
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput placeholder="Category" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="categoryCtrl">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
      <md-option *ngFor="let category of filteredCategories | async" [value]="category">
        {{ category.$value }}
      </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>

    <md-input-container>
      <textarea mdInput ngModel name="details" placeholder="Details" rows="15" cols="60" required></textarea>
    </md-input-container>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="24px">
      <md-checkbox ngModel name="isAdmin">Is Admin?</md-checkbox>
      <md-checkbox ngModel name="isCool">Is Cool?</md-checkbox>
    </div>
  </div>
  <md-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button md-button type="button" (click)="dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
    <button md-button color="accent">Save User</button>
  </md-dialog-actions>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the RxJS `filter` operator when it appears that you should be using `Array.prototype.filter`.

`this.categories` is a `FirebaseListObservable`, so it will emit an array contianing the database reference's child items. That means you are passing an array to the regular expression's `test` method.

You should do something like this:

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

filterCategories(val: string) {
  return val ?
    this.categories.map(list => list.filter(
      s => new RegExp(`^${val}`, 'gi').test(s.$value)
    )) :
    this.categories;
}
```

Also, you might want to move the creation of the `RegExp` to outside of the implicit `filter` loop.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me.  As soon as I start typing all items in the list disappear.   while before nothing was removed.  Do you know of a good way to debug these chained commands(map.filter.test etc)

Comment: I would verify that you are receiving what you are expecting and that the regular expression is also doing what you expect it to. As for debugging composed observables, it would be nice to have better debugging tooling, but I usually revert to using what is basically equivalent to `.do(value => console.log(value))`, but with some pre-defined operators.

Comment: Just realised that it's not working because the list contains unwrapped snapshots - not string primitives - so the category is in the `$value` property and it's that property that needs to be passed to `test`.

Comment: Yep that was exactly it.  I had tried that before but not after implementing your other suggestions.  Thank you so much for your help.  I knew that I was just failing to understand something basic.

Comment: moving the creation of the RegExp outside of the filter loop actually created problems for me.  The code exactly as it is in the answer is what got everything working for me.